# Macro to check range of cells for certain value to hide rows if any cells in the range contain that value?

Tags: excel, vba

Below is the code I have so far:

```
Sub Compare()

Sheets("SCR SYSTEM SPECS").Select
Sheets("SCR SYSTEM SPECS").Copy
Dim WS As Excel.Worksheet
Dim ColumnCount As Long
Dim I As Long
Dim Cell As Excel.Range

Set WS = ActiveSheet    'adjust as necessary
ColumnCount = 12    'adjust as necessary
With WS
For I = ColumnCount To 1 Step -1
    Set Cell = .Cells(3, I)
    If Cell.Value = False Then
        Cell.EntireColumn.Delete
    End If
Next I
End With

ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Button 1", "Check Box 1", "Check Box 2", _
    "Check Box 3", "Check Box 4", "Check Box 5", "Check Box 6", "Check Box 7", _
    "Check Box 8", "Check Box 9", "Check Box 10", "Check Box 11")).Select
Selection.Delete

End Sub
```

What I need is a macro to go below all of this to loop through range B4:L4 and check each cell to see whether it ends with an X or not. This row will contain any combination of the following numbers/text: 1300, 2000, 2000X, 2500, 2500X, 3000, 3000X, 4500, 6000, 7000, 9000. I need to say if none of these cells end in X then hide or delete certain rows. I've been trying to use If Not Like "*X" unsuccessfully. Below is the code I have tried so far which has been unsuccessful. Any help is much appreciated.

```
Dim MyCell, Rng As Range
Set Rng = Sheets("SCR SYSTEM SPECS").Range("B4:L4")
For Each MyCell In Rng
    If Not MyCell Like "*X" Then '''''will only do something if the cell is not blank
    Rows("4:18").Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    'Else '''''if cell is equal to blank
    'Rows("4:18").Select
    'Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
Next
```

This is the altered code I am trying to use to hide rows that contain all 0's but it is hiding the rows whether they contain all 0's or if they contain 2 columns with a 0 then a column with a 4. Please advise.

```
Dim MyCell2, Rng2 As Range
Set Rng2 = Sheets("SCR SYSTEM SPECS").Range("B36:L36")
For Each MyCell2 In Rng2
    If Right(Trim(MyCell2.Value), 1) = "0" Then
    Range("36:36").Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `LIKE` function is tricky, and probably not what you want since it's fuzzy, anyways.

Use the `RIGHT` function:

```
Sub TestThis()
Dim MyCell, Rng As Range
Set Rng = Sheets("SCR SYSTEM SPECS").Range("B4:L4")
For Each MyCell In Rng
    If Right(Trim(MyCell.Value),1) = "X" Then '''''will only do something if the cell is not blank
        Rows("4:18").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        'Else '''''if cell is equal to blank
        'Rows("4:18").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

I also revise the above code to avoid `Selection`, which is unnecessary about 99% of the time.

Because you're looking for an "If NONE of these cells contain..." I would suggest the following additional revision, to `Exit` the loop once the condition is met.

```
Sub TestThis()
Dim MyCell, Rng As Range
Set Rng = Sheets("SCR SYSTEM SPECS").Range("B4:L4")
For Each MyCell In Rng
    If Right(Trim(MyCell.Value),1) = "X" Then '''''will only do something if the cell is not blank
        Rows("4:18").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Exit For '## Exit the loop once the condition is met ##'
        'Else '''''if cell is equal to blank
        'Rows("4:18").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the response David. However, when I enter the code it gives me an error message. It highlights the , before the 1 and gives a Compile error: Expected: Then or GoTo

Comment: Hold on, I might have too many parentheses in there... I'll revise.

Comment: OK try again. There was an extra parenthesis.

Comment: Alright, it's working but it's working backwards. I need the rows to hide if the cells don't contain an X and to stay unhidden if the cells do contain an X. How would I alter the code to do that?

Comment: Change `If Right...` to `If Not Right...` **OR** change the `=` operator to `<>` **OR** change `True` to `False` in the next line (`Rows("4:18").EntireRow.Hidden = True`). Either one should work.

Comment: No problem. If it's working, please consider marking the answer as "Accepted".  Cheers!

Comment: Done, one more question. I am on the same spreadsheet and needing to do the same thing so I'm posting your code I altered a little bit. I need it to check certain rows and if they only contain 0's all the way across I need to hide that row, however, if it contains any number then do nothing. I have edited the post to show the code I'm trying that isn't working.

Comment: Just use the sum function, instead of looping over all the cells in the row: `If Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(rng2) = 0 Then ...`

Comment: Final question David. How would I alter this code to hide rows with nothing in them? The code you gave me worked for hiding rows with just 0's. It won't work for hiding cells with nothing in them because instead of looking for 0's and 4's I have to check for blank cells and cells with numbers such as 1 x 60/45. Please advise

Comment: I have to search say row 42 and if it contains only blanks I need to hide it but if it had blanks and a cell containing 1 x 60/45 I don't need to hide it. I guess the sum function doesn't work because this isn't an actual number and can't be summed so the sum is still 0.

Comment: OK, then try `Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng2)` if that returns zero, then all cells are blank.

Comment: Alternatively, you could always do the loop using the formula like `If Len(Trim(MyCell2.Value)) = 0` which will check the *length* of the value in the cell. That should be pretty foolproof I'd think.